# C++ integer template parameter evaluation

Tags: c++, templates, string-comparison, case-insensitive

This question may be very straightforward but I am rather inexperienced with c++ and got stuck while writing a simple parser.
For some reason one of the string comparison functions would not return the expected value when called.
The function looks like this:

```
template<int length>
bool Parser::compare(const char *begin, const char *str){
   int i = 0;
   while(i != length && compareCaseInsensitive(*begin, *str)){
      i++;
      begin++;
      str++;
   }
   return i == length;
 };
```

The purpose of this function was to compare a runtime character buffer with a compile time constant string vb

```
compare<4>(currentByte, "<!--");
```

I know there are more efficient ways to compare a fixed length character buffer (and used one later on) but I was rather puzzled when I ran this function and it always returns false, even with two identical strings.

I checked with the debugger and checked the value of i at the end of the loop and it was equal to the value of the template parameter but still the return expression evaluated to false.
Are there any special rules about working with int template parameters ?
I assumed the template parameter would behave like a compile time constant.

I don't know if this is relevant but I'm running gcc's g++ compiler and debugged with gdb.

If anyone could tell me what might cause this problem it would be highly appreciated.

The functions used in this piece of code:

```
template<typename Character>
Character toLowerCase(Character c){
    return c > 64 && c < 91 ? c | 0x10 : c;
};

template<typename Character>
bool equalsCaseInsensitive(Character a, Character b){
    return toLowerCase(a) == toLowerCase(b);
};
```

Comment: A version tweaked to use `==` instead of `compareCaseInsensitive()` [returns true](http://ideone.com/ll3KAy) over here when given identical input.

Comment: The problem is probably on `compareCaseInsensitive`.

Comment: I already thought about that but when I inspected the i variable it would evaluate to the same value as length.

Comment: Please show us `compareCaseSensitive`

Comment: checked again: when I lift the function out of the class and change it to a stand alone function it works without a problem.

Comment: If `c` is 'A' (aka 65), then `c | 0x10` is 81, aka 'Q'

Comment: You added the code for `equalsCaseInsensitive` but are calling `compareCaseInsensitive`... which is right?

Comment: Sorry: should indeed be compareCaseInsensitive but I lifted it out of class and changed name for testing purposes.

Comment: And there is indeed an error in compareCaseInsensitive (should be | 0x20 instead of 0x10, thanks for that one!) but when I debugged it it would go through the loop twice and then return false. Probably something went wrong during compilation/debugging. After I changed function names and deleted old object files I couldn't reproduce the weird debug result. Thanks for the help in calling out the bug.

Comment: compare functions usually return -1, 0, or 1 where 0 is a match

Comment: good point, going to change that. I'm probably going to use that function in other places as well and use it for lexicographic compare. currently XML parser is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For doing case-insensitive string comparisons, I would try using the STL function [std::strcoll](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcoll) from the header `<cstring>` which has signature

```
int strcoll( const char* lhs, const char* rhs );
```

and compares two null-terminated byte strings according to the current locale. Or if you want to roll your own, you could still use [std::tolower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) from the header `<cctype>` which has signature

```
int tolower( int ch );
```

and converts the given character to lowercase according to the character conversion rules defined by the currently installed C locale.